# How to count the number of occurences of a word in several files?

Tags: bash, scripting, find

I have a directory containing a lot of files.

I would like to display with one shell command the list of all the xml files in the directory with the number of times a specific word appears in each file.

Like this :

```
file1.xml 333
file2.xml 525
...
file67.xml 767
```

I first devised the command to obtain the number of occurances for only one file :

```
grep -w WORD FILE.XML | wc -l
```

But I hit a snag when I try to use it to do the same thing with all the xml files in one directory.

I tried this command :

```
find . -name "*.xml" -exec grep -w WORD {} | wc -l +
```

and I really thought it would work because I already used several times find in this context but it didn't. Here is the error output :

```
wc: +: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

Anyone knows how I can make this command right please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` has a built-in `-c` option that returns the number of matches. So you don't need to pipe to `wc -l`.

```
find . -name '*.xml' -exec grep -H -c -w WORD {} +
```

The `-H` option ensures that it includes filenames in the output even if there's only one matching file. By default, `grep` only shows filenames in the output when it has more than one filename argument.

Comment: Thx! It works with the `-c` option !!! I have exactly the same output with or without the `-H` option tho.

Comment: You wouldn't have the same output if there's only one XML file in the directory. By default it only shows the filename when it gets multiple filename arguments.

Comment: Ok I made a try. You're right.

Comment: That's what I tried to explain in the last line of the answer.

Comment: Doesn't it just count the number of lines that contain the word?

Comment: @Fravadona you're right. Fortunately for me all the words I count are on different lines. :')